# How to make a bullet separator in android development?

Tags: android-layout

I'm a newbie in android development. I would like to know how to make a bullet separator
like below example :

2:30 am • 29 April 2013

I would like to use it to separate stuffs like date time and tags.

In my XML file, it looks like this :

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/text_date_time"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/text_location"
/>
```

Comment: Can you give a little more context about the mechanisms by which you'd be planning on displaying the bullet point? Using stardard android UI components? Something else?

Comment: I'm using an XML file to show the date time component. The date time will be displayed dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just put the '•' character in the middle of the string, if android does not have the char you want just put an image in between 2 labels.

Comment: I did the first option, which I copied and pasted the bullet into Eclipse. And it works. Thanks for the simple solution. Here is the example in code : textDateTime.setText("2:30 am • 29 Apr 2013"). +1 to  Nicolas Tyler.

Comment: @JohnSmith Please mark Nicolas Tyler's answer as accepted - click the tick under the vote up and down thingie :)